# When i change my bundle ID on xCode the app doesn't behave properly - PhoneGap

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I needed to change my bundle ID to something a little better as it was just my last name. So i changed it to the typical com.companyname.appname and now the app will build but doesn't behave the same. If i change it back to the previous ID then it will work again perfectly. I am using phoneGap. What is the proper way to change the Bundle ID?

Thanks

Comment: Just tried. I went to project, hit clean, then hit build. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in config.xml file after change bundle Identifier in your project.

```
  <widget id="your bundle id" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

How to find: search your old bundle id in your xcode  in search area

[image]

Open your Plist in xcode. then edit your bundle id

or

[image]

Comment: it is at the latest version

Comment: and that is how i am changing it obviously, but when i change it the app stops working

Comment: still no luck with this. if the bundleID is my last name then it works other than that its broke

Comment: are you saying i should change io.cordova.hellocordova to my new bundle id?

Comment: instead of your bundle id

Comment: <widget id="com.lastname.appname" version="0.0.1"     like this?

Comment: but it still says in my plist file that its the old bundle id?

Comment: change all the place where is bundle id present to new one.

Comment: give me a up vote. it helpful future user and you get reputation too